# cumulative distribution functions (CDFs)

Tags: probability, correlation, mathematical-statistics, cumulative-distribution-function

i want to know why is important use CDF for this analysis of TMY (typical meteorological year) because i have the data of the month for compare with the long term mean

This the example of the manual 
[image]

[image]

I have 2 CDF's with equal number of points that I want to compare. These are from:

Temperature of 1 month from 2012

Mean temperature across months

What can I do to obtain this difference, this is from the formula of Finkelstein-Schafer??

the manual is this manual https://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/pubs/tmy2/

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking for here.

Comment: i have an excel with all the data

Comment: Okay but I doubt having data will help us understand what you want. Are you able to edit your question to try to explain in clear, simple steps what the situation is and what you need to know? Perhaps a reference that describes what you're doing in detail would help as well (but you still need to explain in the question). When you say 'the manual', which manual are you talking about?

Comment: ok thanks for the observation,  ready, I already edited it

Comment: I'm still not sure this is sufficiently clear

Comment: what do you need?

Comment: Having computer problems; I have reopened but I will try to come back to identify some specific issues when I can.